# Doesn't having pull up resistors in the I2C pins disables their use as GPIO?

Tags: gpio, i2c

The GPIO 2 and 3 pins are the I<sup>2</sup>C pins and both have 1.8 k ohm pull up resistors. Can they still be used as GPIO pins even with these resistors?

Comment: Don't all the pins have internal pull-ups, or am I mis-remembering?

Comment: @PeteHooper All the GPIO have internal pull-ups/downs which can be switched on/off in software.  I2C SDA/SCL, pins 3/5 additionally have hard wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can still be used as GPIO.

It's best to use something which doesn't waste the hard wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3.  E.g. if they are used as a switch wire the switch so that it is connected between ground and the GPIO.  The switch will normally read high, but will read low when closed.